# Two boxes each share 50% in width

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">

<div style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; padding: 8px; width: 40%; top: 0; left: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; position: relative;">
....
</div>

<div style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; padding: 8px; width: 40%; top: 0; right: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; position: relative;">
....
</div>

</div>
```

My end goal is to have two boxes each sharing 50% of width with margin in-between them.

Instead they are shown below each other which I do **not** want. They appear not to respect their designated position values. (I even set width to only 40% for both, so it was not an issue of all space used.)

For reference: I chose not to use float since I don't want them to realign underneath each another. I chose not to use table display since I would like IE7 compatibility. I have never done much CSS, so my question is hopefully simple to solve (crossing fingers)

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to us

Comment: I added a media query to mine - so that when it goes to the breaking point - it remains side by side - not sure if that works for you.

Comment: When you have relative positioning, the top/right/bottom/left properties do nothing when they're set to 0.

Comment: @cimmanon I figured the right: 0 would place the elements right side to the right edge of parent container. Should I have used 1 instead? If so, doh! :(

Comment: To be quite honest, I am leaning towards using table/table-cell for all other browsers than IE7. And then at serverside detect IE7 useragnt and output HTML table layout. It will give me the advantage that I still can use CSS / media queries for mobile platform. (And modern browsers)

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you are missing either `float: left` (remove `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` values) or `position: absolute`.

If you want width to be fluid but padding to be fixed (or vice-versa), then you need `width: 50%` with [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). This makes the padding *part of* that 50%.

If you want width and padding to both be fluid, this trick isn't necessary. Just use percentage measurements for both so the total is 50% (e.g., `width: 48%; padding: 1%`).

Answer (score 2):

You really just need to float your inner divs, to make it all a bit easier, add `box-sizing` attribute.

Lets say having this HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

And then just add something like this:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

By using `calc()`, you have to subtract the margin of each `.box`. And the use of `box-sizing` property is to avoid that border and padding were added to the width, which is the default behavior on the CSS box model. You should have a look on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) to see compatibilities and the use of vendor prefixes.

There're really more than a way to do the same thing. But I think this one is a very solid way to achieve your goal.

http://jsfiddle.net/gVwar/

Comment: The OP specifies IE7.  `calc()` isn't supported until IE9 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).  Box-sizing requires IE8+.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsbin.com/enenej/1/)?

Check the demo out at the link above.

```
   <div class="box1">X</div>
   <div class="box2">X</div>
```

CSS

```
   * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}


.box1 {
  width: 48%;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid black;
 }

.box2 {
  width: 48%;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid black;
 }


.box1, .box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
  .box1, .box2 {
    width: 46%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1%
}
```

Comment: On my FireFox browser, those two are shown below each other. Not next to each other. (Which is what I want)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/etodoz/3/edit) solves your problem. Error being you didn't float the divs.

**Block level elements will never be placed adjacent to one another when not floated, unless when positioned absolutely or fixed.**

Note: If you want to position your elements with `top, left & right` properties, you'll have to set their `position: absolute`.

Comment: (1) I thought top/left/right would also work with position: relative; I will need to invesitgate. Thanks for info!
(2) Your fiddle still shows the two boxes underneath each other, not side-by-side (checked in FireFox)
(3) The reason I did not use floats is that they float under each another when the user resizes window too small. I want the divs to keep at same line keeping their 50% (I am planning on using media queries to handle different winow/screen resolutions)

Comment: (1) Yes it does in some cases, I don't remember exactly when, but it involves a parent being positioned relatively. (2) Admittedly only checked in Chrome, but I noticed when revisiting the link that the fiddle added some stuff I added later for testing, that's why it doesn't work. I'll rebuild tomorrow if necessary. (3) That's not true unless you set a min-width. If your divs have a percentage width, they will never stack. Check out a framework like Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation, floats are used in almost all CSS frameworks

Comment: 3) I had pondered about min-width, but would prefer if it was not necessary. That said, maybe it would be the easiest solution to try... Hmm... Will do that.